# Java Days elapsed counter from beginning of user specified year

Tags: java, days, elapsed

I am trying to calculate the no. of days elapsed in a year with the year matching the inputted date example:

If the user enters 13/01/2008
it will say 12 days have passed since the beginning of the year

This is my school assignment, Thanks.

so far I have Taken in the input of date and I want to use that to calculate the no. days elapsed in that year.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Locale defaultFormattingLocale
        = Locale.getDefault(Locale.Category.FORMAT);
        final String defaultDateFormat = DateTimeFormatterBuilder
                .getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.SHORT, null, 
                        IsoChronology.INSTANCE, defaultFormattingLocale);
        final DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(defaultDateFormat, defaultFormattingLocale);

        Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a date in the DD/MM/YYYY Format");
        
        String dateString = inputScanner.nextLine();
        try 
        {
            LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse(dateString, dateFormatter);
            System.out.println("Date entered was " + inputDate);
        
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) 
         {
            System.out.println("Invalid date - Enter a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY");
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're already using methods from the java.time class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int daysElapsed(Calendar date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    
    
    long diff = Math.abs(date.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    
    return (int) TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Calendar (along with Date and other similar classes) are obsolete  and should be avoided.  Use only classes from the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: I'm old school, so I tend to forget about the newer packages  But it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

You're already  using classses from `java.time`.  So just do the following:

```
String date = "13/01/2008";
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"));

System.out.println((ld.getDayOfYear()-1) + " days have passed.");
```

prints

```
12 days have passed.
```

Comment: You're already doing it.  After you parse the dateString taken from  the user and it succeeds (Doesn't throw an exception, then just display the information as I did.